# Can I get UNIX file permissions to take effect immediately for all processes?

Tags: permissions, file-descriptors

When I change the permissions on a file using `chmod`, existing file descriptors can continue to access the file under the previous permissions.

Can I cause those existing file descriptors to close or fail or become unusable immediately after the permission change?

Comment: No, you can't. The file modes are only considered upon opening the file. If your question is "philosophical", you may want to read [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/546537/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The kernel doesn't check permissions on file descriptions.  They can even be duplicated to other processes that never had access to the original file by [fd passing](https://openforums.wordpress.com/2016/08/07/open-file-descriptor-passing-over-unix-domain-sockets/).

The only thing I think you could try would be to manually [find out processess](https://superuser.com/a/97871/112499) with open file descriptors, and pull a sneaky trick to close them<sup>1</sup>.  There's an example of such a "sneaky trick" is to attach a debugger (`gdb`) and use that to close the fd.

**This is a very extreme thing to do.** There's no way to know how a process will behave if it's FD is suddenly closed.  In some cases processes may have a file mapped to memory so if you manage to close the file and you managed to remove any memory mapping without the processes expecting it would crash on a segmentation fault.

**Much better** would be to find which processes are using a file and manually kill them.  At least that way you can ask them to shutdown nicely and not corrupt other data.

---

<sup>1</sup> *as mentioned in comments, the best shot of making this work would be to call `dup2` rather than `close` to change the fd to point to `/dev/null` instead of the original file.  This is because the code won't expect it to have closed and may do some very weird and insecure things when the fd (number) gets recycled.*

Comment: @UncleBilly hence I wrote "(and mapping)". Though I'll edit to to make it clearer that this would be a separate step.

Comment: Never use a debugger to close a fd; that will produce extremely dangerous double-close/use-after-close bugs whereby the application **performs operations on the wrong file** if it continues to run. Instead, `dup2` a reference to `/dev/null` over it.

Comment: Without knowing the sementics of the application it's not possible to tell that the /dev/null trick is really safe (i.e. won't produce very unwanted application behaviour), either.

Comment: @JamesToungman that’s very true as described on the last paragraph of the answer.  However there’s a very specific security issue with what happens when a process recycling fds.  The dup2 trick could trip up a process but at least it’s unlikely to trigger a web server to return a private key instead of the front page.

Answer (score 6):

You can't invalidate the existing file descriptors, except through "sneaky tricks" like those mentioned by Philip Couling. However, you can achieve a similar effect in a (reasonably) portable way.

Let's say that you want to prevent processes that already have `foo` open from continuing to write to `foo`. What you can do is: `cp foo foo2; chmod -w foo2; mv foo2 foo`. Now any processes that had the old `foo` open will continue writing to this file, which is no longer known as `foo` (has one fewer hard link than before). None of these processes can affect the new `foo`, since they cannot open it for writing.

If you want to prevent reading, a similar strategy is `cp foo foo2; chmod -r foo2; truncate foo; mv foo2 foo`. Here, the old `foo` is truncated in-place (*i.e.,* reduced to zero size without being deleted) so the processes that had `foo` open will see no content the next time they attempt to read from it, and they can't open the new `foo`. However, this is not guaranteed to work, since if any processes had `mmap`ed `foo`, then it's unspecified whether the truncation actually affects those mappings.

Comment: While not required by POSIX, I believe all current Unix systems use a unified file cache, so the last paragraph should work.

Comment: @Barmar maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but truncating a file mmapped by another process will 100% cause that process to crash when trying to access the mapped memory. And it does not matter whether the mapping is "private".

Comment: Well, maybe not on Hurd. Thence "unspecified", LOL.

Comment: @UncleBilly I was addressing where the answer says "this is not guaranteed to work"

Answer (score 2):

That is a super-interesting question, and researching it actually provided more fun for a Sunday than watching Netflix :-)

- as other answers have answered, not within posix
- dirty tricks: YMMV, and i am pretty sure that the debugger trick needs to be expanded by unmapping the files (and holy cow, that is evil. File descriptors getting invalid between one system call and another is not nice, but portions of data structures vanishing is impossible  to deal with).
- Under Linux: If you look at https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/The_Linux_Storage_Stack_Diagram.svg actually implementing what you suggest in all generality would require you to look up the page cache position for the inodes and personally hunt these down by means unknown (otherwise already mapped memory is still there, without a system call.). (Remark: probably not possible to do it reliably in userspace without locking the access to the page cache and or preventing forking of your process)
- you could (linux) try to use mandatory locking mount options + flock, but I am not sure that you can "steal" the lock

That means:

- we don't like memory mapping
- we don't like to meddle below the FS layer

Depending on your use case I see other possibilities:

- Implement an overlay filesystem. That prevents mapping, and you can filter the calls - should be actually not complicated.
- Use a network file system to do similar things
- And most important: Organize the access to the file via a server process (essentially the same as "implement an overlay file system, but portable" :-))